# How to tackle efficient searching of a string that could have multiple variations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, full-text-search, sql-server-2014

My title sounds complicated, but the situation is very simple. People search on my site using a term such as "blackfriday".

When they conduct the search, my SQL code needs to look in various places such as a `ProductTitle` and `ProductDescription` field to find this term. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Products 
WHERE ProductTitle LIKE '%blackfriday%' OR 
ProductDescription LIKE '%blackfriday%'
```

However, the term appears differently in the database fields. It is most like to appear with a space between the words as such "Black Friday USA 2015". So without going through and adding more combinations to the `WHERE` clause such as `WHERE ProductTitle LIKE '%Black-Friday%'`, is there a better way to accomplish this kind of fuzzy searching?

I have full-text search enabled on the above fields but its really not that good when I use the `CONTAINS` clause. And of course other terms may not be as neat as this example.

Comment: There's probably a cleaner and easier way to do it, but my first thought is to use REPLACE to eliminate punctuation and spaces from both the search term and the columns.

Comment: FREETEXT (as you mention in your answer) is the best solution to handle word variations. But it won't help match a combined word like `blackfriday`, except *maybe* commonly combined words like `dogcatcher`, though I'm not even sure it can do that. Let me know if handling *any* combined word is a requirement and I can help with that.

Comment: @Keith Yes please Keith, its combined words that are killing me! If you have any suggestions I'd be very thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should start by saying that "variations (of a string)" is a bit vague. You could mean plurality, verb tenses, synonyms, and/or combined words (or, ignoring spaces and punctuation between 2 words) like the example you posted: "blackfriday" vs. "black friday" vs "black-friday". I have a few solutions of which 1 or more together may work for you depending on your use case.

**Ignoring punctuation**

Full Text searches already ignore punctuation and match them to spaces. So `black-friday` will match `black friday` whether using FREETEXT or CONTAINS. But it won't match `blackfriday`.

**Synonyms and combined words**

Using [FREETEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx) or [FREETEXTTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx) for your full text search is a good way to handle synonyms and *some* matching of combined words (I don't know which ones). You can [customize the thesaurus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491.aspx) to add more combined words assuming it's practical for you to come up with such a list.

**Handling combinations of any 2 words**

Maybe your use case calls for you to match poorly formatted text or hashtags. In that case I have a couple of ideas:

- Write the full text query to cover each combination of words using a dictionary. For example your data layer can rewrite a search for `black friday` as `CONTAINS(*, '"black friday" OR "blackfriday"')`. This may have to get complex, for example would `black friday treehouse` have to be `("black friday" OR "blackfriday") AND ("treehouse" OR "tree house")`? You would need a dictionary to figure out that "treehouse" is made up of 2 words and thus can be split.
- If it's not practical to use a dictionary for the words being searched for (I don't know why, maybe acronyms or new memes) you could create a long query to cover every letter combination. So searching for `do-re-mi` could be `"do re mi" OR "doremi" OR "do remi" OR "dore mi" OR "d oremi" OR "d o remi" ...`. Yes it will be a lot of combinations, but surprisingly it may run quickly because of how full text efficiently looks up words in the index.

Answer (score 1):

A hack / workaround if searching for multiple variations is **very important**.

1. Define which fields in the DB are searchable (e.g `ProductTitle`, `ProductDescription`)
2. Before saving these fields in the DB, replace each space (or consecutive spaces by a placeholder e.g `"%"`)
3. Search the DB for variation matches employing the placeholder
4. Do the reverse process when displaying these fields on your site (i.e replace placeholder with space)
5. Alternatively you can enable regex matching for your users (meaning they can define a regex either explicitly or let your app build one from their search term). But it is slower and probably error-prone to do it this way

Answer (score 1):

After looking into everything, I have settled for using SQL's `FREETEXT` full-text search. Its not ideal, or accurate, but for now it will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is probably inadequate but do you have any scenarios which wont be addressed by query below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Products 
WHERE ProductTitle LIKE '%black%friday%' OR 
ProductDescription LIKE '%black%friday%'
```

Comment: Well yes because the string itself is a parameter, I don't know what the string would actually be